# How to Add Pagination Bullet in sync with "Swiper Thumb Gallery Loop"

Tags: pagination, carousel, swiper.js

i need help to add pagination bullet in sync with my swiper thumb gallery loop.

In summary, i want a pagination but don't know how to add it and make it  sync with my thumbnail and slider..

Functional will be same as that of my current gallery thumb [output of my code, position where i want to place my pagination](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFE4v.jpg)

Link to my code, cause facing problem adding code in stack overflow itself. Hope you guys don't mind.

https://codefile.io/f/V0EgIWJqb6#

I tried many ways but facing problem syncing with thumbnail and with slider after it gets loop.

I want that as the thumbnail and slider are in sync with each other, likewise, i want pagination bullet above the thumbnail which will show active slide, prev slide, next slide and so..  also it needs to loops like that of swiper thumb gallery.